# Get error "doc.delete" is not a function when trying to delete docs in a Firestore CollectionGroup

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app where a user can create a post. Users can also bookmark these posts. However, when a post author deletes his post that others may have already bookmarked, I need to also automatically delete those bookmarks that are associated to the deleted post.

Here's my data model (when a user bookmarks a post, the bookmark is saved to the user's record in a subcollection called `bookmarks`:

[image]

I've written the code logic to delete a bookmark like so:

```
          const postsQuery = await this.$fire.firestore
            .collectionGroup('bookmarks')
            .where('id', '==', this.post.id)
            .get()
          postsQuery.forEach((doc) => doc.delete())
          console.log('bookmark deleted')
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('error deleteing post.', error)
        }
```

Problem: I get the following console error when trying to delete the bookmark:

```
EditPost.vue?4144:107 error deleteing post. TypeError: doc.delete is not a function
    at eval (EditPost.vue?4144:95)
    at eval (prebuilt-28889c43-f8ea673b.js?f270:18228)
    at eval (prebuilt-28889c43-f8ea673b.js?f270:16453)
    at eval (prebuilt-28889c43-f8ea673b.js?f270:11563)
    at t.inorderTraversal (prebuilt-28889c43-f8ea673b.js?f270:2801)
    at t.inorderTraversal (prebuilt-28889c43-f8ea673b.js?f270:2719)
    at t.forEach (prebuilt-28889c43-f8ea673b.js?f270:11562)
    at t.forEach (prebuilt-28889c43-f8ea673b.js?f270:16452)
    at t.forEach (prebuilt-28889c43-f8ea673b.js?f270:18227)
    at _callee$ (EditPost.vue?4144:94)
```

How can I correctly write this delete logic? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> doc.delete is not a function

This is because `doc` is a [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot?authuser=0) and not a `DocumentReference`. You need to use the [`ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot?authuser=0#ref) property as follows:

```
const postsQuery = await this.$fire.firestore
        .collectionGroup('bookmarks')
        .where('id', '==', this.post.id)
        .get()
postsQuery.forEach((doc) => doc.ref.delete())
```

---

Note that if you want to monitor when all the bookmarks are deleted (`console.log('bookmark deleted')`) you may use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0#batched-writes) (a batched deletion in your case!) or `Promise.all()`

Comment: Thanks for your comment about batched write. I have it partially working, but I will submit another question as I am unsure how to add batch write when using loops.

Comment: @redshift Sure, just tell me when you have posted the new question, I'll answer it with pleasure! :-)

Comment: Here ya go! https://stackoverflow.com/q/67990044/2420614